# Which chili peppers does one use in arrabbiata sauce?

Tags: chili-peppers

I want to make an infusion in whiskey with these peppers. I can't find which peppers are used. The peppers described are dried, long, and thin.

Comment: Can you define abbiachiatta sauce? I can find no reference to it on the web.

Comment: Do you mean arrabiata sauce? (Sometimes spelled with 2 t's.)

Comment: Yes, I may have the wrong spelling. It is an Italian chili pepper sauce used mainly on pasta.

Comment: I went ahead and edited for you - [arrabbiata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrabbiata_sauce) is certainly the common spicy tomato sauce in the US, and sounds kind of like what you originally said.

Answer (score 2):

"Arrabiata" is the Italian word for angry...angry sauce,which is the literal translation for sugo all'arrabiata the spicy Italian tomato based sauce to which you refer.  The spiciness comes from dried red chili. In Italy these red peppers are often referred to as peperoncini.  You would likely get the effect you were looking for by using good quality dried red pepper flakes.

[This question and response addresses Italian peppers](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33838/what-varities-of-chili-peppers-are-most-commonly-used-in-italy).